# How to boot from external display - Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: boot, 22.04, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, external-monitor

I have setup with 3 external monitors while lid of my laptop is all time closed. I power up using button in dock station. In BIOS I switch option to boot up from external monitor.
Everything was perfect but unfortunately recently it is no longer.
When I power up my laptop I can see Ubuntu booting screen on my external monitors and I have time to press 'enter' to go into BIOS. After that there should be window to enter my password for my encrypted disc. Yeah... It used to be...
It was always like that but something went wrong and I am no longer able to see that window. My monitors shows notification "NO SIGNAL HDMI". I have to open my lid up and only then I can see this and enter my password. I can also enter my password like sleepwalker but cmon...

**I am really pissed of by that. I tried every possible restart / plug in out etc.**

Could someone help me please?

---

My specification:

- Laptop - **[Lenovo ThinkPad L15 Gen 1 20U8](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/pl/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-l-series-laptops/thinkpad-l15-type-20u7-20u8)**
- Processor - **AMD Ryzen 7 pro 4750u with radeon graphics x 16**
- Operating system - **Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS**
- Docking station - **[ThinkPad Ultra Docking Station 40AJ](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/pl/products/accessory/docks/thinkpad-ultra-docking-station/40aj)**
- Displays - **[Gigabyte G24F 2](https://www.gigabyte.com/pl/Monitor/G24F-2)**